# GroupBy with after projection to domain model without .ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'am trying to use group by after conversion a data model to domain model that joins another model using `.Include()`.

Our application uses three layers: data, business logic, service (web api). The layers communicate using domain models, api uses data transfer objects to communicate with clients. We using entity framework core 3.1.3 for database access.

The api allows to filter, sort, count and group using query parameters. We got a lib that translate these requests into LINQ expressions and apply it to a `IQueryable<DomainModel>`. To get these queries execute at our database we using `Select` at the `IQueryable` to create a projection.

Now we got a two data models that in one to many relation.

```cs
public class InvoiceDataModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DocumentDataModel> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentDataModel
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public InvoiceDataModel Invoice { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<InvoiceDataModel> Invoice { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DocumentDataModel> Documents { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceDataModel>(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("Invoice");
            c.HasKey(p => p.InvoiceId);
            c.HasMany(p => p.Documents)
                .WithOne(p => p.Invoice);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentDataModel>(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("Document");
            c.HasKey(p => p.DocumentId);
        });
    }
}
```

And the corresponding domain models

```cs
public class InvoiceDomainModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public CustomerDomainModel Customer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DocumentDomainModel> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentDomainModel
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDomainModel
{
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Filter, sort and count works for this. Grouping throws `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlFunctionExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.`

To find what the problem is, I decided to write the LINQ by my own

```cs
_dataContext.Invoice
    .Include(p => p.Documents)
    .Select(x => new InvoiceDomainModel
    {
        InvoiceId = x.InvoiceId,
        InvoiceNumber = x.InvoiceNumber,
        DueDate = x.DueDate,
        InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
        Customer = new CustomerDomainModel
        {
            CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
            CustomerNumber = x.CustomerNumber
        },
        // Adding this does throw
        // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
        // 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlFunctionExpression' to type
        // 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.
        Documents = x.Documents.Select(d => new DocumentDomainModel
        {
            DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
            DocumentNumber = d.DocumentNumber,
            Category = d.Category,
            Type = d.Type
        })
    })
    // Done at logic
    .GroupBy(p => p.InvoiceNumber)
    .Select(g => new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
    .ToList();
```

The problem seems to be the select for documents inside the projection to our domain model. Removing it does the code get work.

I could also fix this adding a `.ToList()` before grouping. But this will leak in massive performance issue as the database contains more then 150 million entries and all of them would be loaded into memory. This is not a option for us.

Does we run into limitation of entity framework core and linq?

Comment: I don't understand why you `Select(x => new InvoiceDomainModel` since you don't use that domain model in `.Select(g => new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()})`? It seems you return `InvoiceNumber` and `Count` so you should not need other properties such as `Documents`, `Customer ` so on..

Comment: The LINQ is ony a example to descripe where the problem is, in this form its not part of my application. My data access class returns a domain model. Logic should be able to group on it, thats not possible. I cant expose my data model to logic layer, this would be architecture breach.

Comment: I see, so I suggest you that don't mix your domain objects with your entities. If you want to apply DB operations via LINQ then use entities not domain objects.

Comment: We dont mix them, we created a projection between them, which work for filter, sort and count. It also does work for entities that not join two data models, including group by.

Comment: @SelimYıldız How about EF Core team fixing their bugs (which this apparently is, looking at the type of the exception and call stack).

Comment: What version of EF Core?

Comment: As I did wrote: 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does we run into limitation of entity framework core and linq?

Unfortunately you are hitting EF Core 3.x `GroupBy` translation bug. There is a similar issue in their GitHub issue tracker [#20887 GroupBy causes exception](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20887), which currently is IMHO incorrectly closed as duplicate of [#19929 Query: Support GroupBy when it is final operator](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19929), so I posted comment there referring to this post.

Current workaround (not sure if and how you can plug it in your query pipeline) is to pre-select (into anonymous type or the same type) the columns needed by grouping key / aggregates, e.g. insert before `GroupBy` the following:

```
.Select(p => new { p.InvoiceNumber })
```

or

```
.Select(p => new InvoiceDomainModel { InvoiceNumber = p.InvoiceNumber })
```